# Scaling a rotated ellipse

Tags: matlab, scale, ellipse

I have a function that draws an ellipse respecting some major axis (vx) and minor axis (vy) scales rotated clockwise by an angle a. I would like to adjust it so that the unrotated ellipse satisfies the equation:

```
(x / vx)^2 + (y / vy)^2 = s
```

For some value s which is passed in.

```
function [] = plotellipse(cx, cy, vx, vy, s, a)
    t = linspace(0, 2 * pi);
    x = cx + vx * cos(t) * cos(-a) - vy * sin(t) * sin(-a);
    y =  cy + vy * sin(t) * cos(-a) + vx * cos(t) * sin(-a);
    plot(x,y,'y-');
```

Answer (score 1):

The usual equation for an ellipse, which you have implemented correctly, is

[image: \left(\frac{x}{vx}\right)^2+\left(\frac{y}{vy}\right)^2=1]

To reduce the desired equation to the same form, divide through by `s`:

[image: \left(\frac{x}{vx\sqrt{s}}\right)^2+\left(\frac{y}{vy\sqrt{s}}\right)^2=1]

Now `x` and `y` become

```
vxs = vx / sqrt(s)
vys = vy / sqrt(s)
x = cx + vxs * cos(t) * cos(-a) - vys * sin(t) * sin(-a);
y =  cy + vys * sin(t) * cos(-a) + vxs * cos(t) * sin(-a);
```